# uploading the data and image into the php server from Android like submission of registration form with image

Tags: php, android, image-uploading, multipart

my app contains a registration form with some fields like firstName,lastName,email,password and image which are to be uploaded into the server with the post method (whatever the concept like Multipart).

```js
/*MultipartEntity entity2 =new MultipartEntity();
   entity2.addPart("pic", image);
   httppost.setEntity(entity2);*/
      
  /* Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.icon);           ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream); //compress to which format you want.
            byte [] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();
            String image_str = Base64.encodeBytes(byte_arr);*/
   
   // Add your data
   List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
   nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("first_name",firstName));
   nameValuePairs
     .add(new BasicNameValuePair("last_name",lastName));
   nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email",email));
   nameValuePairs
     .add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",password));
   nameValuePairs
   .add(new BasicNameValuePair("pic",image));
   
   httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
   
   
   /*
       MultipartEntityBuilder entityBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
       entityBuilder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

       entityBuilder.addTextBody("first_name",firstName);
       entityBuilder.addTextBody("last_name",lastName);
       entityBuilder.addTextBody("email",email);
       entityBuilder.addTextBody("password",password);

       File file = new File(image);
       if(file != null)
       {
           entityBuilder.addBinaryBody("pic", file);
       }

       HttpEntity ent = entityBuilder.build();
       httppost.setEntity(ent);*/
   
      /* HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
       HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
       result = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
       Log.v("result", result);*/
   

   // Execute HTTP Post Request
   HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
      HttpEntity entity=response.getEntity();
   InputStream is = entity.getContent();

   String response_ = convertStreamToString(is);
   
  System.out.println("Successfully posted to server "+response_);
  
   return response_;

  } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  } catch (IOException e) {
```

```js
lastname = editLastName.getText().toString();
    email = editEmail.getText().toString();
    password = editPassword.getText().toString();
    
     Log.e("path", "----------------" + picturePath);
     
           // Image
          /* Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
           ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
           bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bao);
           byte[] ba = bao.toByteArray();
           ba1 = Base64.encodeToString(ba, Base64.DEFAULT);
    
           Log.e("base64", "-----" + ba1);*/
     
        Bitmap bitmapOrg= BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgPath);  
       ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
       bitmapOrg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bao);  
       byte [] ba = bao.toByteArray();  
       String ba1=Base64.encode(ba, Base64.DEFAULT).toString(); 
    

                 System.out.println("image before RegisterAsync "+ba1);
    
    // connection object creation
    detector = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());

    RegisterDownloadHelper();
    
    if (detector.isConnectingToInternet()){
     new RegisterAsync(MainActivity.this,
       RegisterDownloadHelper,url,firstname,lastname,email,password,fileName)
       .execute();
    } else {
     manager.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this, "ALERT",
       "Please Check The Internet Connection !", false);
    }
```

Comment: You can upload the image to your site and store the link in your database.

Comment: with this code I'm unable to store image into the server.. it's showing an error that the image uploading is not a type of jpeg or jpg or png..

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to implement an IntentService and notify status with broadcast intents. please checkout complete code from github 
https://github.com/alexbbb/android-upload-service

let me know if you facing any problem to integrate this code

```
//this Method call Intent Services 
public static void uploadFile(Context context) {
    Settings.openDataBase(context);
    final String serverUrlString = "http://test/webservice.php";
    final String fileToUploadPath = Settings.getProfilePicPath();
    File fileObj = new File(fileToUploadPath);

    BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileObj.getAbsolutePath(), bmOptions);

    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
    Bitmap decoded = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray()));

    Uri tempUri = getImageUri(context, decoded);
    File finalFile = new File(getRealPathFromURI(context,tempUri));

    final String paramNameString = "image";
    final UploadRequest request = new UploadRequest(context, UUID.randomUUID().toString(), serverUrlString);
    request.addParameter("type", "account_edit");
    request.addParameter("username", Settings.getUserName());
    request.addParameter("email", Settings.getUserEmail());
    request.addParameter("user_id", Settings.getUserId());

    request.addFileToUpload(finalFile.getAbsolutePath(), paramNameString, finalFile.getName(),
            ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
    request.setNotificationConfig(R.drawable.app_icon, context.getString(R.string.app_name),
            context.getString(R.string.uploading), context.getString(R.string.upload_success),
            context.getString(R.string.upload_error), false);
    try {
        UploadService.startUpload(request);
    } catch (Exception exc) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Malformed upload request. " + exc.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }
}
```

Comment: can't we implement this with other concepts like Multipart entity in AsyncTask. As I'm new to android,I'm unable to get your implementation.

Comment: it's very simple to integrate just download library project https://github.com/alexbbb/android-upload-service/tree/master/src/com/alexbbb/uploadservice and add project as library and used it